# React Vite gives 404 Error on internal Page reload

Tags: reactjs, vite, custom-error-pages

I have deployed my code into IIS Server.
The problem is that when i click the navigation it works fine.

But when i refresh the internal page like this
http://url.amazonaws.com:5002/Prefrences

they give me an error of

404 - File or directory not found.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    // Ensure this option is set to 'production'
    mode: "production", 
  },
});
```

this is my vite.config.js  file.

what should i do in this?
or any thing else?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the deployed page doesn't use vite. You have to configure your server to render `index.html` for every route

Comment: How are you hosting your code? You probably need to serve dist/index.html as a fallback for every request as it's a SPA.

Comment: do yo know. how to configure?

That's my exactly question.

Comment: @TalhaAbbas The original URL you posted was running on an IIS server, so something like this should work -- https://dev.to/sumitkharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-1ied -- refer the last part (the url rewrite module)